# I can't find the database

Tags: asp.net, database, sql-server-2008, web-config

I am taking over the maintenance of a website. Virtually no documentation. I hope that this kind of question is "ok" here ...

Right now, I am trying to locate/view the database but I can't find it.

This is the only connectionString in web.config:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add connectionString="Data Source=YPOC\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Marco;User ID=yyy;Password=xxx;" name="DefaultConnectionString" />
</connectionStrings>
```

QUESTIONS:

1) are these parameters equivalent?

```
 a) Database=Marco

 b) AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Marco.mdf

 c) Initial Catalog=Marco
```

2) if the answer to #1 is "yes", then I should find a database file called Marco.mdf in the App_Data folder, right?

3) but #2 can't be correct, because I do not see a database file called Marco in the App_Data folder ... ;-x

4) where in the world is carmen sandi ... oops, I mean Marco.mdf ?!

---

RELATED QUESTIONS:

I had to copy all the files from a production server called YPOC. In the web.config, I think I need to change "Data Source=YPOC\SQLEXPRESS" ... my SQL Server Instance Name is "SQLEXPRESS" ... therefore, should I change the DS to "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS"?

---

In the App_Data folder, I found ASPNETDB.MDF ... in Server Explorer, I try to connect to view the tables, but I get an error message:

"...cannot open because it is version 661. This server supports version 655 and earlier"

I did some research and it appears that version 661 means that it needs SQL Server 2008 R2 ... but I have that installed already ... ;-(

---

I'm used to a shared hosting environment where the SQL Server DB is set up and it's easy to connect. Here, it is on a dedicated cloud server (unmanaged) and I'm been thrust upon new territory where I can't even find the database ... ;-(

Any help is greatly appreciated ...

- nano

Comment: Have you tried to use window's search? It's difficult for us to tell you where is a file in the computer.. if you can use Sql-Server and log on and see the database (to make some querys for example), in the properties of the database, "files" option, you can find the path where the .mdf and .ldf are. That's because you can set the path where will be these files when Create or Restore database.. So, if you have access in SQL-Server 2008, there you got your answer.

Comment: Sorry, the connectionString wasn't showing. I put 4 spaces in front and now it shows. - I did try windows search prior which came up negative. I think I got it wrong. It is not Marco.mdf (db file) that I'm looking for. It is a database Marco on the SQL Server. It must be, right? But how do I access this database from my dev computer when I don't know the SQL server address, etc? Again, I'm coming onto this project cold with no documentation ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"But how do I access this database from my dev computer when I don't know the SQL server address, etc?"

- I found the Marco database. It is on SQL Server that is located on an unmanaged web server account. The way to access the database is to use a Remote Desktop Connection, then use SQL Server Management Studio that is located on the server (not my dev desktop). The SSMS then found the server/database and voila, connected ... my confusion was in trying to connect using SSMS from my dev desktop directly instead of using SSMS located on the server via RDC ...

Answer (score 2):

Stop, stop, stop, stop, stop using the `User Instance` and `AttachDbFileName` nonsense. Please. You will be much more sane if you forget they exist. I'm totally serious. The user instances feature has been deprecated for a reason.

Take your MDF file, which you can find by searching using Windows Explorer (if you've been using this `user instance` feature, you will probably find multiple, and I have no suggestions for determining which one is the right one). Once you've found the one you want to use, attach it to a *proper* instance of SQL Server using `CREATE DATABASE Marco ... FOR ATTACH_REBUILD_LOG`. Your connection string should then point to your server (yes, `.\SQLEXPRESS` should be fine if you are connecting locally), and should refer to your database by logical name (e.g. `Marco`, no path information to a specific MDF file).

Also you'll want to install [Service Pack 1 for SQL Server 2008 R2](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=26727). It seems like you created a database in a post-RTM build of SQL Server 2008 R2 (or in 2008 with SP2+).

Comment: THanks Aaron, I thought I had SP1 on already, but I think it was for SQL Studio Mgmt that I did it for ... I did the SP1 for the 2008 Express and the database opened up ... one less block to worry about ... thanks. - Also, I think I now realize a mistake in my OP; I made a note in the comment above to ElVieejo.